# Vue and Vuex: computed property isn't called when changing state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm quite new with Vue and Vuex so please bear with me.

I want to make the computed function `versions()` get called when I change `state.template`, but I'm failing to do so. More specifically, when `state.template.versions` changes.

This is part of the component that I want to re-render when `state.template.versions` changes. You can also see the computed property `versions()` which I want to be called:

```
    <el-dropdown-menu class="el-dropdown-menu--wide"
      slot="dropdown">
      <div v-for="version in versions"
        :key="version.id">
           ...
      </div>
    </el-dropdown-menu>
    ...
    computed: {
      ...mapState('documents', ['template', 'activeVersion']),
      ...mapGetters('documents', ['documentVersions', 'documentVersionById', 'documentFirstVersion']),
    versions () {
       return this.documentVersions.map(function (version) {
          const v = {
            id: version.id,
            name: 'Draft Version',
            effectiveDate: '',
            status: 'Draft version',
          }
          return v
        })
    },
```

This is the `getter`:

```
  documentVersions (state) {
    return state.template ? state.template.versions : []
  },
```

This is the `action`:

```
  createProductionVersion (context, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      documentsService.createProductionVersion(data).then(result => {
        context.state.template.versions.push(data)  // <-- Here I'm changing state.template. I would expect versions() to be called
        context.commit('template', context.state.template)

        resolve(result)
      })
```

This is the `mutation`:

```
  template (state, template) {
    state.template = template
  },
```

I've read that there are some cases in which Vue doesn't detect chanegs made to an array, but `.push()` seems to be detected. Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Any idea on why the computed property is not being called when I update `context.state.template.versions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function won't get called because this is wrong:

```
context.state.template.versions.push(data) 
context.commit('template', context.state.template)
```

the `context.state` object just points to your current state nothing more.

My suggested solution will be:

1. First You need to declare your store state correctly

   ```
   state: {
      template: {
         versions: []
      }
   }
   ```
2. You need to update your getter to look like this with no unnecessary
   conditioning:

   `documentVersions: state => return state.template.versions,`
3. add a new mutation

   ```
    ADD_VERSION: (state, version) => {
      state.template = {
        ...state.template,
        versions: [...state.template.versions, version]
       };
     }
   ```
4. your action should like this now:

   ```
      createProductionVersion({commit}, data) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            documentsService.createProductionVersion(data).then(result => {
              commit('ADD_VERSION', data);
              resolve(result);
            });
          });
        }
   ```
5. In your component I suggest to change your computed property from a function
   to an object that contains a `get` and `set` methods (`set` is optional)

   ```
   versions: {
     get() {
       return this.documentVersions.map(function (version) {
         const v = {
           id: version.id,
           name: 'Draft Version',
           effectiveDate: '',
           status: 'Draft version',
         }
         return v
       })
     }
   },
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ahmed Jaouadi, really appreciate it. I'll try to apply your changes and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 3):

The issue may come from `state.template = template`. You guessed correctly that it was a reactivity issue, but not from the Array reactivity, but the `template` object.

Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion. This includes affecting a complex object to a property. For that, you need to use `Vue.set`.

So your mutation should be :

```
template (state, template) {
  Vue.set(state, "template", template)
},
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: Also, you should only be changing state in mutations. You can set strict mode so it errors when you do this. https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html

Comment: @GavinBruce I agree, OP should also avoid naming mutations and state properties with the same name, but IMO this is out of scope.

Comment: @Seblor thank you for your answer. I've applied your suggested solution, the `Vue.set` statement is executed but the computed function is still not being run.

Answer (score 1):

I think this error occurred because you did not declare your store state correctly. Make sure you have the `versions` property in your `template` object.

```js
state: {
  template: {
    versions: []
  }
}
```

This way, any changes in the `versions` property will be detected by vue.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've applied your suggested solution, but the computed function is still not being run. Any other idea?